# Why does the value of shunt resistor need to be very high for solar cell's greater efficiency?

Tags: resistance, solar-cell, semiconductors, shunt, solid-state-devices

In the circuit equivalent of a solar cell, shunt resistor is described as "The irregular polycrystalline lattice grain boundaries that resist to the flow of electrical current in the silicon material."

If this explanation is correct, shouldn't it be "lower shunt resistance increases the current flowing".

However the shunt resistor is connected in parallel to diode. That means "higher the shunt resistor greater the current output".

How and why so? I thought not having many grain boundaries is what makes the monocrystalline cells more efficient than polycrystalline solar cells?!

[image]

https://www.scirp.org/html/7-6401007/fe85a7b6-645d-4341-8f35-dde69e519017.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

Warning this is a crosspost, though no one answered my question anyway I share the links:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645123/why-does-the-value-of-shunt-resistor-need-to-be-very-high-for-solar-cells-great

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44659/problem-with-relationship-between-shunt-resistance-and-grain-boundaries-in-a-sol

Comment: As the community rules suggests, I put a hyper-link to the original post in the stack exchange Physics site, though there are no answers given to me there, that's why I had to cross-post it.

Comment: You shouldn't cross-post--ask for it to be moved, instead.

Comment: `How and why so? I thought not having many grain boundaries is what makes the monocrystalline cells more efficient than polycrystalline solar cells?` How grain boundaries affect both series resistance and shunt leakage losses is a physics and materials science thing, not really electrical engineering.

Comment: I don’t know the intricacies of crystal lattice photon absorption efficacy but I do know the Rs is inverse to the cell area and the Rp affects Voc but more importantly, maximum power transfer point occurs when the load matches the panel’s negative incremental impedance. This also happens to be equal to the ratio of open circuit voltage and short-circuit current Zmpt=Voc/Isc which is typically 82% of Voc and declines  towards 72% at 10% of max solarity.

Comment: series resistance should be 0 ideally and shunt should be infinite. this is also what your material says. imperfections deteriorate both properties. shunt resistance is in parallel to the load basically through the solar cell itself. both resistances scale inversely to the area which is usually big. therefore shunt is much more important usually and avoiding it is important.

Comment: @tobalt the crystal lattice irregularities=shunt resistance in a solar cell causes the overall current output to decrease. However, if you connect shunt resistance parallel to the diode as shown in the picture above, increase of its resistance will increase the current output. There is a problem here.

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll Increasing the shunt resistance decreases the current in the shunt itself, so increases the current remaining for the load, which is the useful output of the cell.

Comment: @Neil_UK It is said that higher shunt resistance = high defects on solar cell crystal = lower total current output = lower solar cell efficiency ; so, It must be in series not in parallel to the diode. Since, Parallel means, higher the shunt resistance = more total current output. However defects lowers the total current output of a solar cell! Gotta be in series! Please explain I am confused. What I say makes total sense...

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll I think you're investing too much into the model. The model summarises what is happening in the real solar cell, it doesn't drive what's happening. The solar cell does what the solar cell does, and then popularisers try to explain what's happening in simple terms. If they choose too simple a route, make some unstated assumptions, then they end up confusing people. A cell with lower losses is better than one with high losses. Load dependent losses are series, load indep losses are parallel. Relative importance depends on load. Defects are good and bad, for different aspects.

Comment: @Neil_UK what do you think about my explaination? Any curciut model has to be correct though, it is very simple thing, what we are arguing here is the simplest thing ever series vs parallel thing. My explaination above makes perfect sense to me. But you guys and the model itself insists that it must be parallel. However any defect just decreases the total current output so must be connected in series. What is wrong about it please tell me somebody!

Comment: Prrhaps the best thing you could do is purchase a real panel and do some experimenting.

Comment: @SolarMike yeah gimme the money and I'll purchase the panel.

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll `Any curciut model has to be correct though,` No. All models are wrong, but some are useful. This one is not useful for what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: Shunt resistance is a parasitic loss. Of course it reduces efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this explanation is correct, shouldn't it be "lower shunt
> resistance increases the current flowing".

No.

> However the shunt resistor is connected in parallel to diode. That
> means "higher the shunt resistor greater the current **output**".
>
> How and why so?

The cell generates a current proportional to light. Current that goes through the shunt resistance bypasses the output. The higher the shunt [resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance) the lower the 'shunt' current is, so more of the generated current gets to the output.

> I thought not having many grain boundaries is what makes the
> monocrystalline cells more efficient than polycrystalline solar cells?

Yes. Monocrystalline cells are more efficient because they don't have defects that allows current to 'leak' internally through the cell instead of going to the output.

This is all perfectly obvious, so I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: It is said that higher shunt resistance = high defects on solar cell crystal = lower total current output = lower solar cell efficiency ; so, It must be in series not in parallel to the diode. Since, Parallel means, higher the shunt resistance = more total current output. However defects lowers the total current output of a solar cell! Gotta be in series! Please explain I am confused. What I say makes total sense... @Bruce Abbott

Comment: _"It is said that **higher** shunt resistance = **high** defects on solar cell crystal"_ - not in anything you have shown us. Your ringed bullet point says "**low** shunt resistance due to material defect". Another says "high **conductivity** paths". Conductivity is the inverse of resistance. The final one just says "parallel resistance", implying the presence of a resistance lower than infinite or an open circuit. You do know that R = V/I means higher resistance = lower current, right?

Comment: "not in anything you have shown us" please look at last picture in the OP. @Bruce Abbott

Comment: https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/shunt-resistance     Here it says "shunt resistance=material defects", I think, "increase in material defects = reduce in total current resistance, that's why monocrystal is more efficient than polycrystal."

Comment: _"Parallel means, higher the shunt resistance = more total current **output**. However defects lowers the total current output of a solar cell!"_ - the diode, the shunt resistance and the series resistance are all _inside_ the cell. Only current that gets to the output (where RL is connected) can be measured and used. The rest is absorbed inside the cell. The output does not include the _internal_ current that goes through the diode and shunt resistance.

Comment: Your link says _"**Low** shunt resistance causes power losses in solar cells by providing an **alternate current path** for the light-generated current."_. An alternate path _inside_ the cell means less current _output_.

Comment: However, increase in defect in material must decrease its efficiency thats why mono is more efficient than polycrystal. You guys and the website I put its link are telling me that increase in shunt resistance gives greater current and efficiency. How is this possible?? @Bruce Abbott

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126403/discussion-between-bruce-abbott-and-physicssolvesall).

Comment: If, shunt resistance=material deficit, then low shunt resistance=material deficit is a good thign not a bad thing. Website says "low material defect=shunt reisistance" is bad thing!!! @Bruce Abbott